I using openxml to add image into a xlsx file. excel can not open
I use openxml add image to xlsx's supertable. I use 'wps' can open this file looks normal but cannot open by 'excel'.
I use <Open XML SDK 2.5 Productivity Tool for Microsoft Office> to validate this file,

Error Part: /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml
Error Node Path: /x:worksheet1
Related Node Type: Drawing
Description: The element has unexpected child element 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main:drawing'.

I don't know which element had problem, I want to find problem element.


I manually added the image to the xlsx file and compared it to the file that I couldn't open, and I didn't see any extra nodes.

if not set excel‘s supertable，this file can be open by excel after use openxml add image.
